# JQuery, how to make div disappear when clicked anywhere out of it?

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to achieve the following behavior:

When link "Option" with DivA id is clicked, the DivB should show up with fade in effect. If I click the link "Option" again as well as if clicked anywhere else in the page except of the DivB inside, the DivB should dissapear again.

This is my HTML code:

```
<a href="..." id="DivA">Option</a>
<div id="DivB">
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my JQuery code. It is wrong, if the DivB is hidden and I click anywhere in the document, the DivB appears.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).click(function () {
        $("#DivB").fadeToggle("200");
    });
    $("#DivA").click(function () {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;       
    });
</script>
```

Where's the mistake? Thanks for help.

Comment: within your code you have:- when the document is clicked, toggle the fade of DivB. So the behaviour you are getting is what you have written

Comment: `.focus()` and `.focusout()` are both very real possibilities for an alternative to this. Be careful with `.focus()` though, as using it on non-visible objects will cause errors in IE (Go figure).

Comment: e is not defined. Add it as a parameter to the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Uk57k/)

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click",function (e) {
     if (e.target.id=="DivA") {
       $("#DivB").fadeToggle(200);
       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;
     }
     else if ($("#DivB").is(":visible")) {
       $("#DivB").fadeOut(200);
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm commenting to let you know that I stole your "Live Demo" stuff. It looks cool.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', function( evt ) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        if ( evt.target.id == 'DivA' || $('#DivB').is(':visible')) 
             $('#DivB').fadeToggle();
    });
</script>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/nR6e3/1/

Comment: That also works, harder to make sense of but works - you missed the stopPropagation though

Comment: I use the toggle on the link, but no need to toggle on the click outside since we already know that it is visible

Comment: Note taken, edited on both counts =) Although, `eventDefault()` is just as adequate really.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click",function () {
   if ($("#DivB").is(":visible")){
       $("#DivB").fadeOut(200);
   }
});

$("#DivA").click(function (e) { // you need place 'e'(for event handling)
    $("#DivB").fadeIn(200);
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var container = $("your selector here");
    
        // if the target of the click not the container or not a descendant of that container
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            container.hide();
        }
    });
```